# Docker compose project in Azure with multiple yaml files?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-service

I am currently constructing a docker project that is to be quite generic in question, to work with several of our sites. The way I have solved that is to have multiple docker-compose yaml files, one main file containing all common configuration and setup, and separate files for each site. And I start it using:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.site1.yml up
```

Our plan is to use Azure for production and staging environment. But we have never deployed a docker-compose project there. When I read about it online, all I can find is how to use it with a single docker-compose.yml file.

Does this mean that our current setup won't work in Azure? If so, any suggestions on how to restructure it?
And if multiple yaml files work in Azure, where can I find documentation about this?

To clarify, if possible I would like to accomplish a solution that:

- Involves only docker/docker-compose and Azure stuff, no OS-dependant shell scripting
- Works both in local environments (Windows and MacOS) and Azure
- Doesn't contain duplicate configuration files

Comment: What did you end up doing? Looking for the same solution. Can create images by manually editing for each environment and pushing to specific containers, manually again.

Comment: @Mukus After struggeling with multiple problems when using their built in docker/docker-compose solution I realized that it was not worth all the hazzle. So we ended up with using a virtual machine with docker installed. Then all the annoying problems went away, and any new problems were easy to troubleshoot.